# Overloading operator< for priority queue

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, priority-queue, conditional-operator

I am trying to make a priority queue of a class I made like this -

```
std::priority_queue<Position> nodes;
```

I overloaded the < operator in Position like this -

```
bool Position::operator<(Position& right) {
    return (fvalue < right.getFValue());
}
```

However, whenever I try to compile I get this error message saying the < operator is not overloaded -

```
error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’
position.h:30: note: candidates are: bool Position::operator<(Position&)
```

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a side note: `return (fvalue < right.fvalue);` will probably be simpler and reduces the public interface you need to maintain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Relational operators shouldn't change the operands.  Try:

```
bool Position::operator<(const Position& right) const {
```

My guess is that either `__x` or `__y` (or both) are `const`.  You can't call a non-const member function on `__x` if it's `const`, also you can't pass `__y` as the `right` parameter if `__y` is `const` and `right` is not.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's preferable not to overload the comparison operators just to satisfy a collection.  (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Operator_Overloading). It's better to use comparator objects or functions, if possible.  If your operator defines how these objects are intrinsically ordered, rather than just what their priority should be in the queue, then it's OK.  But if not, you could get into trouble if another developer uses your operator in another context.
2. I'm not sure what `fvalue` is, but it's possible that it may not have `operator <` defined for it.